# Script awk to make an HTML file

Tags: html, awk

I have one CSV file of suicides between 1985 and 2016, and I wanted to make an HTML from one output that I have generated using awk. With this command I counted the total amount of suicides in every country, and also I included GDBpc. The code I used and the output that I obtained with that code is the following:

```
tail -n +2 suicidios_final.csv | awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "Country" " " "Year " " "GDPpc" " " "Suicides"}1 {a[$1 " " $2 " " $11]+=$5} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' > suicides1.txt

(head -n 1 suicides1.txt && tail -n +2 suicides1.txt | sort) > suicides.txt

cat suicides.txt

Country Year GDPpc Suicides
Albania 1987 796 73
Albania 1988 769 63
Albania 1989 833 68
Albania 1992 251 47
Albania 1993 437 73
Albania 1994 697 50
Albania 1995 835 88
Albania 1996 1127 89
Albania 1997 793 170
Albania 1998 899 154
Albania 1999 1127 139
Albania 2000 1299 54
Albania 2001 1451 119
Albania 2002 1573 133
Albania 2003 2021 124
Albania 2004 2544 146
Albania 2005 2931 0
Albania 2006 3235 0
Albania 2007 3863 124
Albania 2008 4672 160
Albania 2009 4387 0
Albania 2010 4359 96
Antigua and Barbuda 1985 3850 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1986 4740 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1987 5595 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1988 6693 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1989 7407 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1990 7744 1
Antigua and Barbuda 1991 7976 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1992 8087 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1993 8453 1
Antigua and Barbuda 1994 9062 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1995 8636 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1998 10078 0
Antigua and Barbuda 1999 10378 0
Antigua and Barbuda 2000 11021 2
Antigua and Barbuda 2001 10468 2
Antigua and Barbuda 2002 10499 0
Antigua and Barbuda 2003 10878 1
```

I have the output in one .txt folder and I would like to make an HTML with it. The script that Im using to do this is

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {
    split("80,80,150,150,", widths, ",")
    print "<style>\
        .my_table {font-size:8.0pt; font-family:\"Verdana\",\"sans-serif\"; border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse; }\n\
        .my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black;}\n\
        .my_table th {text-align: left;}\
    </style>"
    print "<table class=\"my_table\">"    
}
NR == 1{
    print "<tr class=\"header\">"
    tag = "th"
}
NR != 1{
    print "<tr>"
    tag = "td"
}
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print "<" tag " width=\"" widths[i] "\">" $i "</" tag ">"
    print "</tr>"
}
END { print "</table>"}' suicides.txt > table.html
```

But with this script I create one HTML like this:

```
Country     Year    GDPpc   Suicides
=====================================
Albania     1987    796     73
Albania     1988    769     63
Albania     1989    833     68
Albania     1992    251     47
Albania     1993    437     73
Albania     1994    697     50
Albania     1995    835     88
Albania     1996    1127    89
Albania     1997    793     170
Albania     1998    899     154
Albania     1999    1127    139
Albania     2000    1299    54
Albania     2001    1451    119
Albania     2002    1573    133
Albania     2003    2021    124
Albania     2004    2544    146
Albania     2005    2931    0
Albania     2006    3235    0
Albania     2007    3863    124
Albania     2008    4672    160
Albania     2009    4387    0
Albania     2010    4359    96
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1985    3850    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1986    4740    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1987    5595    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1988    6693    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1989    7407    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1990    7744    1
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1991    7976    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1992    8087    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1993    8453    1
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1994    9062    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1995    8636    0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1998    10078   0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     1999    10378   0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2000    11021   2
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2001    10468   2
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2002    10499   0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2003    10878   1
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2004    11535   2
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2005    12649   0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2006    14114   0
Antigua     and     Barbuda     2007    15775   1
```

As you can see, the countries that have spaces in names, for example, "Antigua and Barbuda", are separated by columns in the HTML, and I would like to have them in the first column, related with the countries.

Someone know what could be happend and how could I solve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to maintain commas as the field delimiter within suicides.txt. You can then use commas as the field separator when generating the html and this should overcome the spaces issue

Comment: @RamanSailopal you were right! I delemited the .txt folder with commas and I added to the awk command the sentence FS = "," and it works, thank you! If you want to write your answer I will validate it, regards!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you have not used commas in the suicide.txt file.

If you use commas, then you can use commas as the field separator when generating the HTML and the spaces in names won't cause an issue.